# Draw particles with Additive but without make transparency against the background in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, particles

I have a typical fire particle effect. (i am not going to show the particle code, the default demo particle at the open of the particle editor works as example).
I need to check the Additive option to make the particles sum theirs colors to reach the desired effect of fire.
Later, in my LibGDX game, the fire particle effect draws against a blue sky background. The fire effect do a transparency agains the blue background and the fire seems pink.
Is nice as magic fire, but i want to draw a normal fire. In black background it seems ok.
How i can archive a normal fire, without sum their color with the background, but without check the needed Additive option in the particle effect?
I have test several things, without any result...

Comment: Try using pre-multiplied alpha (blend mode `GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA`). This is decent compromise between additive and alpha blending. You'll need to create an alpha channel in your image (maybe a good place to start is just transfer the luminance of your color channels to the alpha channel). Tweak it by brightening or darkening your alpha channel until you get a good compromise for the number of particles you're using.

Comment: Qhen you say to create an alpha channel to the image... do you refer to the background? It is not an imagen, only a Gdx.gl.glClearColor(). It have the alpha to 0xff (i have probed different values, rendering the particles with batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ONE,GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA), but without any perceptible changes...)

Comment: I'm talking about in your paint program that you use to prepare the particle PNG image. You need to create an alpha channel in the file to store the alpha values. If using Gimp, I would start by flattening to one layer, then right click the layer and choose Add Layer Mask, and select Grayscale Copy of Layer when you do it. Then right click the layer and choose Apply Layer Mask, which will transfer the mask to the alpha channel. Then save as a PNG, but keep it open in Gimp. You'll want to iteratively come back and adjust brightness/contrast on the mask (undo back to it having a mask each time).

Comment: Ah, ok. I use the particle.png of example, the one inside of gdx-tools.jar. This particle have an alpha channel, but i am been playing with the alpha opacity, with any success. The fire seems worse, but the pink effect remains. I suppose the way is to use my own particle.png, and do as you say.